# regex to change sed command+special characters?

Tags: sed, cmd

I'm using CMD on Windows Xp to replace special text with Sed. I'm using this command for replace special characters like `$ or *` :

```
sed -i "s/\*/123/g;" 1.txt
```

the previous command does not work because i have `\`, `"` and other special strings that sed use to make regex. The escape character `^` doesn't work well because sed no give me error but nothing change inside files. 
 To change this text `"{\*)(//123/$$` i try use this command: 
 `sed -i "s£"^"{^\^*)(//123/^$^$"£xx£g;" 1.txt`
  `£` is the delimiter, `xx` is new text..but nothing change
How i want to turn text like this?
 `sed -i^/\\*$/$[{" ;" 1.txt` into `xx`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo '"{\*)(//123/$$' | sed "s/[\"][{][\\][*][)][(][/][/]123[/][$][$]/xx/"
xx
```

Comment: yes..now it works..exactly command is  `echo '"{\*)(//123/$$'`  
`sed -i "s/[\"][{][\\][*][)][(][/][/]123[/][$][$]/xx/" 1.txt` But if i want replace `[`, `'` and `^`? i put it into `[]`?

Comment: @user143822 yes e.g. `echo "'[]^"|sed "s/[][^']/x/g"` = `xxxx`